# Why is the "flag for attention" link sometimes missing from posts in review?

Tags: support, flags, review

When perusing the post on [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review), I noticed that the "flag for attention" link is missing from some posts.  Why is that?

[image: snippet of review page showing some posts with and without the flag]

Comment: +1 for the screen shot, meets all meta requirements

Comment: @waffles: Who am I to break with such a venerable and hallowed meta.stackoverflow tradition as free-hand circles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the post has an upvote <strike>or has been accepted</strike>, the ability to flag the post from the `/review` page is suppressed. If you still think it should be flagged, click through to the post since the option to flag can still be accessed there.